# What is the name of this type of mark?

Tags: punctuation, diacritics

Is there a name for this mark?  It sits below a letter as a means of showing an abbreviation.  (In this case, Established abbreviated to Estd.)

I've seen it used in the form below in place of an apostrophe for a contraction.  Frequently, it's used to abbreviate *William* to *Wm*.

I know there's a [diacritic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic) mark called an underdot, but I'm not sure this qualifies as a diacritic since it's not meant to influence sound value of the words.

It's some sort of stylized period (full stop for my British friends).  But, I'm wondering if there's a term for using it to raise the letter above it in this usage.

[image: Raised letter diacritic]

Comment: It's a stylised ***underline***. From [Wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_indicator) *The practice of **underlined** (or **doubly underlined**) **superscripted abbreviations** was common in 19th-century writing*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers This is clearly correct.  Please turn that into an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a stylised ***underline***. From [Wikipedia...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_indicator)

> *The practice of **underlined** (or **doubly underlined**) **superscripted abbreviations** was common in 19th-century writing*.

Comment: This suggests the question of why and how this became the convention?  When did it change to the use of apostrophes?

Comment: I'd guess the underline *became* the convention in the context of medieval scribes or earlier. Paper & ink being relatively expensive, they'd be under pressure to abbreviate ***and*** write extra small letters in many "predictable" contexts. Retaining the underline for such condensed lettering (such as might have been used temporarily for alignment of the *main* text, but then erased) looks like an obvious way to improve legibility in such contexts. But ***less*** necessary as we get progressively more accurately *printed* text through C19.